# Bootstrap plugin does not work with Vue2

Tags: jquery, vuejs2

I tried to add a bootstrap plugin called `touchSpin` to one of my components, but it isn't working.

**Code**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  components: {
    'my-component': myComponent,'card':card
  },
  mounted(){
    $('.commission').TouchSpin({
                min: 0,
                max: 2,
                step: 0.0001,
                decimals: 4,
                boostat: 5,
                maxboostedstep: 10,
                buttondown_class: 'btn btn-white',
                buttonup_class: 'btn btn-white'
            });
  }
});
```

Here is the fiddle to show the problem.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/n24jo0dc/83/)

Comment: Why are you using jquery with vue?

Comment: @Mardoxx can you suggest me any Vue plugin equivalent to TouchSPin ?

Comment: Yeah, write it yourself, should take a couple hours unless you decide to add every feature under the sun like most 3rd party libs do.

Comment: what a mess js buddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, you are *not* using Vue 2.

I upgraded your fiddle to use Vue 2 and fixed the remaining issues.

Your code is calling the TouchSpin initialization when the Vue is mounted, but that is too early: the `back` component isn't mounted to the DOM until later. I added it to the `back` component and modified `back` to use a ref pointing to the commission input.

```
Vue.component('back',{
 template:`#back-template`,
  mounted(){
    $(this.$refs.commission).TouchSpin({
      min: 0,
      max: 2,
      step: 0.0001,
      decimals: 4,
      boostat: 5,
      maxboostedstep: 10,
      buttondown_class: 'btn btn-white',
      buttonup_class: 'btn btn-white'
    });
  }
})
```

This way, whenever the `back` component is mounted, it will be initialized with TouchSpin.

Here is your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n24jo0dc/102/).